# Index is not used when doing a query with PostgreSQL CTE

Tags: postgresql, index, cte

Given I use the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    asset_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    event_id varchar(255) NULL,
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

and the following Index :

```
CREATE INDEX idx
ON operations ( event_id);
```

When I run the following query

```
WITH ROWS AS (
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS row_num
FROM
    operations
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ROWS
WHERE
    row_num = 1
    AND event_id IN ('bb87d265b3c82098f7cd6913a4eb6df2', '4780d32075328c6f6f0ebe4e7fd48662')
    AND operation != 'DELETE';
```

the index is not used  :

```
Subquery Scan on rows  (cost=7159.77..7909.77 rows=1 width=598) (actual time=48.159..48.160 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: (((rows.event_id)::text = ANY ('{bb87d265b3c82098f7cd6913a4eb6df3,4780d32075328c6f6f0ebe4e7fd48662}'::text[])) AND ((rows.operation)::text <> 'DELETE'::text) AND (rows.row_num = 1))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 20000
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=7159.77..7559.77 rows=20000 width=598) (actual time=38.352..46.491 rows=20000 loops=1)
        Run Condition: (row_number() OVER (?) <= 1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=7159.77..7209.77 rows=20000 width=590) (actual time=38.343..39.519 rows=20000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: operations.asset_id, operations.updated_at DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2911kB
              ->  Seq Scan on operations  (cost=0.00..467.00 rows=20000 width=590) (actual time=0.012..2.993 rows=20000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.144 ms
Execution Time: 48.436 ms
```

If I remove the row_num condition, then the index is used. e.g :

```
WITH ROWS AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    operations
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ROWS
WHERE
    event_id IN ('bb87d265b3c82098f7cd6913a4eb6df3', '4780d32075328c6f6f0ebe4e7fd48662')
    AND operation != 'DELETE';\
```

Can someone explain why the first query does not use the index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain why the first query does not use the index ?

Because limiting the result set to specific `event_id` values affects the calculation of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)` -- row numbering can obviously change if limited to only a subset of `event_id`s. As a result, the condition on `event_id` can only be applied to the output of the CTE, not to the underlying table.

If you want the index to be used, include the `event_id` condition in the CTE.

Comment: That's a super clear explanation, thank you